# How to change board values from A to B

Tags: prolog

This is my first program in Prolog and I am facing a problem, I have been asked to change board values from A to B as below :

Board size : 6 columns x 6 rows

Initial value of cells : A

Final cells values : B

Condition :

> When an A is turned over, it becomes a B and its neighbors are turned Z over. If its neighbors are A's, they become B's and conversely if they are B's, they become A's.

By neighbors they mean the boxes in the same row and column. which means if we change a cell value, 4 other cells values will change as well.

I have been looking everywhere, watching videos and reading available examples, to get the way how shall i proceed. 
I am not asking for the code itself, i would like to understand if someone can explain to me how to start/think.

I have tried this :

```
    :- dynamic ligne/2. 

matrix([ 
[1,2,3,4,5,6], 
[7,8,9,10,11,12], 
[13,14,15,16,17,18], 
[19,20,21,22,23,24], 
[25,26,27,28,29,30], 
[31,32,33,34,35,36] 
]). 
ligne(X, Ligne) :- 
        matrix(M), 
        nth0(X, M, Ligne), 
        assert(ligne(X, Ligne)). 
colonne(X, Colonne) :- 
        matrix(M), 
        maplist(nth0(X), M, Colonne). 

voi_vert(X, Y, Z) :- 
       ligne(X, Ligne), 
      Y is X+1, 
       nth0(Y, Ligne, Z), !.
```

Comment: You need to give an example where your solution does not work as expected.

Comment: Since the cells actually have a specific value, you should set your matrix to all `'A'` (or all `a`). If you want to change state, you need an input matrix and an output matrix. But I'm left with a question: what is your predicate supposed to do? If you already know the final state is all `'B'` (or all `b`) are you supposed to keep track or list all of the in between states? Also, when the matrix changes state, is it just one cell at a time, starting at row 1, column 1? How is the rule to be applied? And what is `Z` when you say, *... its neighbors are turned **Z** over.*?

Comment: Yes the state of cells will change one by one until it becomes all B.  this is why i am struggling with the condition they gave. It would be easier if i could share the PDF i have

Comment: Here's the code i started with ::- dynamic ligne/2.

matrix([
[1,2,3,4,5,6],
[7,8,9,10,11,12],
[13,14,15,16,17,18],
[19,20,21,22,23,24],
[25,26,27,28,29,30],
[31,32,33,34,35,36]
]).

ligne(X, Ligne) :-
matrix(M),
nth0(X, M, Ligne),
assert(ligne(X, Ligne)).

colonne(X, Colonne) :-
matrix(M),
maplist(nth0(X), M, Colonne).

voi_vert(X, Y, Z) :-
ligne(X, Ligne),
Y is X+1,
nth0(Y, Ligne, Z), !.

Comment: Edit your question and put code that you have there. Too hard to read in comments since it's unformatted, and others will miss it. I'm still not sure what you want the predicate to do (as in, what solutions it is supposed to find). It would help if you could give an example query.

Comment: You just added the same code as another comment. It's no more readable than it was last time you posted it as a comment. Under the text of your question is an "edit" link. Click that and edit the content of your question. Don't add code as a comment.

Comment: Thank you, i have edited my question.  Regarding your question about the predicate : this is what i am trying to understand. they would like me to change Board value from A to B. cell by cell until it becomes all B. and everytime we change A to B the neighbours change as well.